# Is it possible to remove property from Custom Class in c#

Tags: c#

```
public class abc
{
   public int id{get;set;}
   public string name{get;set;}
}
```

I want to remove property name from class abc dynamically. is it possible in c#?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: No, it's not. You can create a separate class without it.

Comment: This can't be done on run time. Once compiled and a class definition is set.

Comment: See [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject).

Comment: No, You can not

Comment: Erm, Interface, anyone? Not really "dynamic" but I suspect that OP doesn't really mean "dynamic".

Answer (score 1):

No, after compilation the class definition can't be changed. What you can do is. Make a list of properties you want to Ignore.

or you can Create a custom attribute. Add it on the property then get the List of Properties excluding the ones with that Attribute

For example

```
public class abc
{
   public int id{get;set;}
   [IgnoredProperty]
   public string name{get;set;}
}
```

Now In Loop For example you can do this.

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(abc).GetProperties().Where(x => !Attribute.IsDefined(x,typeof(IgnoredProperty))).ToList())
{

}
```

This can be the attribute Class

```
public class IgnoredPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: under which namespace IgnoredProperty keyward comes  in c#?

Comment: Its a custom Class. Attribute that i defined. you can see at the end of this answer

Comment: By convention, your attribute class should be named `IgnoredPropertyAttribute`.  This is in line with the other .Net attribute classes.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway you'r right!

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring "dynamic" for the moment, here's what you could do with interfaces:

```
public interface IAbcId {
    Id {get; set;}
}

public class Abc : IAbcId {
    public Id {get; set;}
    public Name {get; set;}
}

....

public class Consumer {

   void CallingFunction()
   {
      var obj = new Abc();
      // obj will have Name and Id properties visible here
      ConsumingFunction(obj)

      // or
      IAbcId iAbc = new Abc();
      //iAbc.Name will not be visible here
   }

   void ConsumingFunction ( IAbcId item )
   {
       // item will only have Id property visible.
   }

}
```

Comment: useful suggestion